# implement Authorization & Authentication in Java With Domain Driven Design

Tags: java, domain-driven-design

My question is simple, i just want to implement DDD in Java with Authorization & Authentication for a login with diferent Roles, can Help me with this topic? documentation, VideoTutorial or any opinion will help me, sorry if this question is duplicated or is not suitable, i will modify it

Comment: Authentication/rization, security is are not the concerns of DDD. You do it the usual way, using a separated security layer. What do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these links could help you:

[Domain-Driven-Design: Authentication and User Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002462/authentication-and-user-tasks)

[Authentication and Authorization in DDD](https://medium.com/@martinezdelariva/authentication-and-authorization-in-ddd-671f7a5596ac#.k1cuayl4b)